# Get max value every Day

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I use Grafana 7.5 and Prometheus;

My data:

```
my_total{app=“portal”,module=“java”,} 20.0
my_total{app=“portal”,module=“python”,} 33.0
my_total{app=“portal”,module=“ruby”,} 16.0
my_total{app=“portal”,module=“go”,} 7.0
my_total{app=“portal”,module=“c”,} 15.0
```

My data will be cleared every morning. I used bar gauge now.

I want to sum by module and every day max(or last not null) value

My query is

`my_total{job=“$job”,app=“$appRepeatVar”} != 0`

`$appRepeatVar` → I have multiple apps, and I used repeat panel

I have tried to set Min step → 1d and panel → Display → Calculation = total

It looks like what I want, but the data doesn't contain today's data.

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6smZG.png)

I don't know how to write the query for what I want.

Comment: Explain what exactly do you want to see. Is it maximum over last 24h? Or is it last value of yesterday? Or is is it last value before previous counter reset?

Comment: my max value is the last value of a day(23:59:59)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query:

```
my_total{job="$job",app="$appRepeatVar"} and on() hour() == 23
```

It will only return values that where scraped between 23:00 and 23:59.

Set in configuration of you panel Value options > Calculation > Last* (Last non-null value), and you'll see last metrics value of previous day